# Why do we get empty responses in requests for js bundles served from chrome diskCache since chrome v111?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

Our react app based on react v18.2, Node.js v18.15 and WebPack v5.76.2 randomly started failing requests for diffents js bundles from chrome diskCache. (Chrome Version 111.0.5563.111) The requests are correctly categorised as "200 / from disk Cache" but the response stays empty until we run into a chunkload Error because of timeout [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ6dQ.png) [emptyResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qctGr.png) [chunkloadError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyC9J.png)

These Requests where correctly fullfilled up to and including Chrome major version 110. It is not always the same bundle that cannot be loaded. The file that is requested from cache exists, so the data should be there. There where no major changes in the app and i cannot find other persons having the same issues with chrome version 111. I submitted the error here: [Chromium Issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1426471), but so far nobody seems to have the same issue. We tried different systems, clearing all caches, even a fresh install on a vm. The problem persists. It can even be replicated with the newest Chrome nightly build. (v113.0.5668.0) Has anybody expierenced this before?